# How to retrieve user content of a Facebook group through the api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

is there anyway to query the Facebook api for a particular groups user content?

the Facebook api groups feed only retrieves posts by the group(admins) itself.
If it can be done , I don't seem to be able to see it in the documentation

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the group-id/feed only return the group admins' post. In my case I can see exactly the same content as in the group's timeline.